# Is it possible to use root user of the system as admin user for keycloak

Tags: keycloak, wildfly-10

we are using keycloak in our product. I am trying to find a way to integrate root user of the machine hosting the keycloak as keycloak admin. Main criteria is on the machine in which keycloak is installed root should be able to access keycloak functions as keycloak admin without providing password. Is it possible now, if possible how to do this. 
Let me know if you need more information. 
Thanks, 
Naga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use admin CLI on the server https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#the-admin-cli

Comment: Hi Jan, I hope you are referring the service account way of using admin cli and answer looks very promising I try to see if it suits my need. Thanks